# looking for jQuery seekAttention plugin

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the jQuery seekAttention plugin that used to be at http://enhance.qd-creative.co.uk/demo/seekAttention/ but now that is non-existent.  That's a nice little plugin to darken the whole page except one element for a short time.  Searching on google for the plugin yields dozens of results, but they are all pointing to that same resource above, like www.webappers.com/2008/09/25/seek-attention-jquery-plugin/.

Does anyone have a copy to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.shiguenori.com/material/seekAttention/

Comment: Yes, that is the one, thank you very much.